# Firebase function - How to include external style.css in index.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

External style.css file is not working after deploying on server

My index.js and styles.css is in same directory.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send(
    `<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    Hello ...
    </body>
    </html>
    `);
});
```

Comment: Apparently the "root" of the Cloud Function html response is not the same than the one of the public/static folder in hosting. You could reference the style sheet with the full path https://[yourproject].firebaseapp.com/style.css

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions HTTP triggers do not serve static content (such as HTML, CSS, and JS files) by default.  HTTP triggers are primarily intended for you to write code that responds to HTTP requests, like API calls.

If you want to serve static content along with HTTP requests, you should look into using [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) along with Cloud Functions.  Firebase Hosting will serve your static content, and when [configured properly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), it will also forward some URLs to Cloud Functions that can be serviced by code you write.

Your other option is to configure an express app in Cloud Functions, and set up some routes with it so that incoming requests that go directly to Cloud Functions can be served by content that you deployed with your functions.  But I think using Firebase Hosting is probably the more common and useful option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the direction @Doug . I experimented with the express app option because I had to migrate existing code. It works however there are two main issues for me: 1. When serving a view or static content. One probably wants to have a vanity URL, which needs fb-hosting. 2. Additionally serving any static content will be much faster through hosting than through my custom express setup inside a function, which only works if I call the function-url directly anyway.